# Google OAuth 2.0: Refresh access_token and New refresh_token

Tags: google-oauth, refresh-token

**Problem**

I am perplexed when refreshing an `access_token` with a previous acquired `refresh_token` does not return a new `refresh_token`.

**Google OAuth 2.0 Steps**

***Request `authentication_code`***

The following URL, opened in default browser, is requesting authentication code, with `access_type=offline` to return `refresh_token` applying returned code to retrieve `access_token`:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
access_type=offline
&prompt=consent
&response_type=code
&client_id=[** CLIENT_ID **]
&redirect_uri=http://localhost
&state=[** STATE **]
&scope=https%3a%2f%2fwww.googleapis.com%2fauth%2fuserinfo.email%20https%3a%2f%2fwww.googleapis.com%2fauth%2fuserinfo.profile%20https%3a%2f%2fwww.googleapis.com%2fauth%2fdrive
```

***Parse `redirect_uri` for `authentication_code`***

The query string properties of the returned `redirect_uri=http://localhost` are parsed as follows:

```
{
  "state": "[** STATE **]",
  "code": "[** AUTH CODE **]",
  "scope": "email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive openid",
  "authuser": "1",
  "hd": "[** HOST DOMAIN **]",
  "prompt": "consent",
  "session_state": "[** SESSION STATE **]"
}
```

***Request `access_token` using `authentication_code`***

Using returned `[** AUTH CODE **]`, request `access_token` and `refresh_token`:

```
curl "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token" \
--request POST \
--silent \
--data 'grant_type=authorization_code
  &code=[** AUTH CODE **]
  &client_id=[** CLIENT_ID **]
  &client_secret=[** CLIENT_SECRET **]
  &redirect_uri=http://localhost
  &state=[** STATE **]'
```

Response includes both `access_token` and `refresh_token`:

```
{
  "access_token": "[** ACCESS_TOKEN  **]",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "refresh_token": "[** REFRESH_TOKEN  **]",
  "scope": "openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "id_token": "[** TOKEN ID **]"
}
```

***Refresh `access_token` using `refresh_token`***

Next testing out `refresh_token` to refresh `access_token`:

```
curl "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token" \
--request POST \
--verbose \
--connect-timeout 60 \
--silent \
--data 'grant_type=refresh_token
  &client_id=[** CLIENT_ID **]
  &client_secret=[** CLIENT_SECRET **]
  &refresh_token=[** REFRESH_TOKEN  **]'
```

Response includes `access_token` but not `refresh_token`:

```
{
  "access_token": "[** ACCESS_TOKEN  **]",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive openid",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "id_token": "[** TOKEN ID **]"
}
```

***Save `refresh_token`?***

However, it appears that if I reuse the initially provided `refresh_token=[** REFRESH_TOKEN  **]`, it is still good in refreshing `access_token` indefinitely.

Therefore, it seems `refresh_token=[** REFRESH_TOKEN  **]` must be stored after the initial consent, which is odd for OAuth 2.0 service.

**Previous Posting**

There was a previous **Stack Overflow** posting in March 2015:
[Google OAuth 2.0 Refresh Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29056587/google-oauth-2-0-refresh-token)

> To get a new refresh token for your client you first need to revoke
>   the existing/old refresh token by revoking access for your client in
>   the Account Permissions tab for your Google account and then ask for
>   access_type=offline again.

In other OAuth 2.0 services, a new `refresh_token` is provided every time a refresh request is performed, and does not require going to

**Summary**

Is there any other way to get a new `refresh_token` every time it is used to a get a new `access_token`? Other OAuth 2.0 solutions are not so complicated in handling refresh.

Thank you, appreciate any response.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, at Google's OAuth2, there are no methods for retrieving the refresh token using the refresh token. Can I ask you about the reason that you are required to retrieve the refresh token using the refresh token? And, in your case, for example, how about using the service account? In this case, the access token can be directly retrieved without the process for retrieving the authorization code. If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for your reply. I have found that since this is the way Google OAuth 2.0 provides a `refresh_token` only upon the initial request of `access_token`, then I must work within these bounds and save it.

Comment: May i ask what type of client credentials you have created that it doesn't give you a new refresh token every time you request one with Curl?

Answer (score 1):

you can remove the autorization for the app, which will force you to re-autorize and get a new refresh token.
it's not something you will want to do on a daily basis but it's great if you forgot to write down the refresh_token.

look for your app **Google Account** > **Security** > **third-party apps with account access**

Answer (score 0):

Since the initially provided `refresh_token` is valid indefinitely in refreshing an `access_token` and it works, okay then.